# Chromecast update meta data for stream without restarting stream

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

I'm initially casting in iOS with this code:

```
metadata setString:lblSongInfo.text forKey:kGCKMetadataKeyTitle];
[metadata setString:currentStation.stationName
             forKey:kGCKMetadataKeySubtitle];

[metadata addImage:[[GCKImage alloc]
                    initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString]
                    width:300
                    height:300]];

//define Media information
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
[[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:
 streamURL
                                    streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeLive
                                   contentType:@"audio/mp3"
                                      metadata:metadata
                                streamDuration:0
                                    customData:nil];

//cast audio
[_mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:TRUE playPosition:0];
```

How can I update just the meta data for this media item (title, subtitle, and image) without reloading the audio stream again? I don't want an interruption in playback. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey Codeman, did you find a solution for your requirement? I'm at the same position of writing a custom receiver and wondered if you had success with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own custom receiver to be able to receive data out-of-band; if you stick with the Styled/Default receivers, those receivers will not be able to receive that type of messages. To send pure data to a receiver, you have two options:

- Use the customData field that is available in some media control commands, or
- Add a new namespace and use that to send data whenever you want.

The first option is limited to those scenarios where it is enough for you to send data when trying to send a media control command to the receiver.

In your case, the cleanest solution is to use the second option, but you can potentially use the first option and send a collection of metadata when you, say, load the media and then have a custom logic on the receiver to extract that collection and update the metadata following your own logic (e.g. periodically). If that satisfies your requirements, then you won't be needing a new namespace but that has its limitations and creating a namespace is truly trivial.

Comment: Thanks Ali. Can you point me in the right direction to some sample code for the namespace solution with updating the meta data? I would need to update the meta data every time the song changes in my audio stream. Thank you.

Comment: It is very straightforward, please take a look at this Github project: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android in which a simple channel/namespace is set up to communicate with the receiver. The receiver code is in there too so you can see both ends.

Comment: There is also a similar ios sample which does the identical thing: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios

Comment: For a streaming radio app, would you recommend that the app (sender) have a copy of the stream playing but muted, and sending updated meta data when the song changes to the custom receiver? Or should the custom receiver notify the sender when meta data changes in the stream? Trying to figure out the best approach. Thanks!

Comment: If your receiver can detect that, it would be much better for it to do that; when it catches a change, it "broadcasts" a message to that effect (possibly passing the relevant data as part of the message) so any connected sender can update its UI accordingly. In the official SDK, a receiver has two modes for sending a message: it can either send it to a particular sender or it can send it to all connected ones (broadcast); in your case broadcast makes more sense and easier; you don't need to loop through each connected device and send the same message to individual ones.